# Name of purple hardcover book covered in a soft fabric with fables, fairy tales, or similar stories

Tags: identification-request, physical-books

I remember being gifted as a child some kind of hardcover book that had a purple colored soft-touch cover; I think it was some kind of fabric. There was also a purple ribbon as bookmark.

I think it was a collection of short stories, children's stories, or folk stories. The look of the book was certainly aimed towards being read by or to a child, and the stories themselves were appropriate.

I can't remember the name of the book or its cover. I could be completely wrong, but I think there might have been a desert on the cover, or an elephant, possibly set at night with a crescent moon. All of this imagery might be wrong, since it's been over 20 years since I've seen it. It's the purple fabric cover and ribbon bookmark that stand out most prominently in my memory.

Is anyone here familiar with this book and can help identify it?

It was not Grimm's Fairy Tales.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the stories?

Comment: Could you please [edit] in when this was?

Comment: [The Violet Fairy Book](https://www.amazon.com/Violet-Fairy-Dover-Childrens-Classics/dp/0486216756)?

Comment: Hi Zhro, and welcome to LitSE. What an intriguing question. There is quite an extensive list of prompt questions for identification requests [here](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info). Can you take a look over them and add any extra detail you can think of? Even small things can help.